# Google Classroom API integration with swift

Tags: swift, rest, google-api, google-classroom

I want to link my iOS app with Google Classroom on swift. My current goal is to be able to get a list of all the courses I am enrolled in.

Here is the code I am currently using

```
        func googleClassroomList()   {
        
        //let sharedInstance = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
        //let handler = sharedInstance
        googleClassroomService.apiKey = "AIzaSyBOGamjhRuu45T2jT7Qa3LmtntSwgIxeqo"
        let query = GTLRClassroomQuery_CoursesList.query()
        
        query.pageSize = 1000
        
        let classQuery = googleClassroomService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { ticket , fileList, error in
        
        if error != nil {
            let message = "Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")"
            print(message)
        } else {
            if let list = fileList as? GTLRClassroomQuery_CoursesList {
                self.fileList = list
                print("List: \(list)")
            }
            else {
                print("Error: response is not a file list")
            }
            }
            
    }
    )
    }
```

Here is the error message:

```
        Error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I don't understand where I attach the OAuth access token, I tried putting it under apiKey but I don't really understand what I am supposed to do. For reference, I am using this auth scope. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to sign-in using Google, and Google will manage the OAuth 2.0 token for you.

Here you have the instructions:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

Also make sure to set the service.authorizer property when you are actually signed in:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {

    guard let user = user else {
        return
    }
    
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.setLoggedOut(loggedOut: false)

    self.myClassroom.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
    self.showClassroomClasses()
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented Google Sign In, and I am able to access google drive with this Google Drive Picker [https://github.com/ConfusedVorlon/HSGoogleDrivePicker] and I go through the sign in screen when getting to my app.

Comment: Have you also set googleClassroomService.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()? I will include my sign() method to show how  did it.

Comment: haha thank you so much, the problem is that I initialized the googleClassroomService twice in my code, so the authorizer was reset, thank you! However my code is running "error: response is not a file list" do you have any ideas on why this is the case?

Comment: What you get is a GTLRClassroom_ListCoursesResponse, not a GTLRClassroomQuery_CoursesList.